# Size image in layout to maximum width without pushing other items out of view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to layout a cell in a ListView with a header, central image and a footer.
The cells will be a fixed height and I want the image to be proportionally scaled up to the maximum width possible without pushing the footer out of the view.
Is this possible in an XML layout?

I have set up a simple example with this layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="100dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="footer"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The footer is not displayed when the height is constrained as above:

[image: No Footer]

I understand that "match_parent" is probably not what I want for the ImageView width, but how can I configure the sizing of the image such that it will only use the available space?

Comment: can you share some layout screenshot which you are expecting?

Comment: @indramurari the only thing missing from the screenshot above is the "footer" text. It has been pushed out of the view. What I would like is for the image to be shrunk only by enough to fit the footer into the view.
All the layouts I have tried have either pushed the footer out like the above screenshot or have shrunk the image down so it is tiny.

Comment: May be you can try with Relative Layout. Have both the TextViews first, header aligned to parent top, footer aligned to parent bottom. Then make the ImageView, match_parent, below header and above footer. Hope that help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @I_A_Mok here is the revised layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="150dp"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="footer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
    android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```